# .chm editor which can merge a lot of referenced files

Tags: windows-7, chm

Very rarely do I ever work on something like this, so maybe it will be better if I first explain what I have and what I want to accomplish, before asking for your help.

I have a lot of .chm files (around 40) which are all in the same folder. They are part of a help system which has been worked on in that way. There is a table of contents file, and then every chapter is in its own file.

When you open the TOC, and then click on Chapter2 a new window with Chapter2 opens. Then another with Chapter 2, Part 1. And so on.

Is there a way that all these files could be merged in one altogether, so that they could be worked on as one big file? Without the constant referencing?
It would also be of use to get a list of all the files a particular file is referncing (linking to).